# I'm setting up EGRESS to access AWS RDS from GKE

Tags: kubernetes, ip, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-rds, egress

I think public access is dangerous, so I want to build EGRESS and add only the egress ip to the whitelist.

**

1.Because GKE is public, CLOUD NAT, which is private, is not included.

2.I've never used TERRAFORM, so I want an answer other than TERRAFORM.

3.VPCs and VPNs are also difficult to understand.

**
This is the currently set EGRESS.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-egress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
      networking/allow-internet-egress: "true"
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to: 
      - ipBlock:
    #static google ip
          cidr: xx.xxx.xx.xxx/32
```

Again, I can't connect to the database.
someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can follow and use the Terraform : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/nat-gateway/google/latest/examples/gke-nat-gateway

it will create the Public NAT for you with **Egress** **IP** that you can **whitelist** into the **RDS**.

Github repo : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/v1.2.3/examples/gke-nat-gateway

You can use the **shell script** which will take 2-3 variable input and invoke the Terraform automatically.

**No** changes are required into the **Terraform**, you can also use the Button in Github to run directly on **GCP cloud shell** if you don't have experience with **TF**.

Comment: I've tried both shell and terraform, but this throws an error in apply.

Comment: Share the error that you getting .